# simple python web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I have the following python code

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'https://www.url.com/?q=715/6+3 TI'
page = requests.get(url).text.encode('utf-8').strip()
tree = html.fromstring(page)
price = tree.xpath('//span[@class="regular-price"]/text()')
print(price)
```

however it is not returning the price from the page as expected
it is returning:

```
['\n                                            ', '                                    ']
```

I can't figure out why the xpath is not finding the correct price from the page.

Python 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting `text` from a wrong tag.
`<span class="regular-price">` doesn't have any `text` of its own. Instead, get the text from the only child element of this tag:

```
price = tree.xpath('//span[@class="regular-price"]/span[@class="price"]/text()')
```

Answer (score 0):

`text()` xpath function will return immediate child text element. How about suing `text_content()` method of element which return all contained text (not only direct children text node):

```
tree = html.fromstring(page)
price = [x.text_content().strip()                                # <---
         for x in tree.xpath('//span[@class="regular-price"]')]  # <---
print(price)
```

prints

```
['£585.00']
```